# Refinish shower pan

Tags: bathroom, shower

We have a nasty shower pan in our master bath that has been stained since we bought the house, i assume it is fiberglass.

No amount of cleaning and chemicals has been able to clear this thing up!

I know there are kits out there to redo showers, etc.

Since it works fine but looks bad, is there a smart way of refinishing it?

[image]

Comment: Have you dealt with removing the iron and/or manganese in the water that causes those stains?

Answer (score 2):

There are refinishing (paint-epoxy) products out there.

My suspicion is that you have not yet been aggressive enough with your cleaning. You need a good, aggressive cleaning product (like my preference, Comet cleanser) and a stiff bristle brush or coarse scouring pad. Combined with *a lot* of elbow grease, that pan will look much better (also all the grout lines too).

Note- the refinishing products out there *will not work* without the same type of aggressive cleaning first...

Comment: I'd follow this approach but I would try Tilex, then rinse thoroughly, then do it again with  Barkeeper's Friend and after that I'd plug the drain and fill the pan with enough undiluted bleach to cover the bottom, and leave that for 10 minutes.   Through all this I'd open windows, wear goggles and already-ruined clothing.